# CoreData concurrency and releasing objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

I'm currently validating our new CoreData architecture which is being used in a multi-threaded environment. For analyzing I'm using [GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging](https://github.com/GrahamDennis/GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging) which prints a warning, every time a ManagedObject is accessed from the wrong thread / queue (as far as I understood).

Now I'm getting tons of warnings like this:

`Invalid concurrent access to managed object calling 'release'`

I was able to put a break-point where the warning is generated and the code looks like this:

```
-(MyObject*) createMyObject {
    return (MyObject*)[self insertNewObjectEntityWithName:@"MyObject"];
}

-(NSManagedObject*) insertNewObjectEntityWithName:(NSString*) entityName {
    __block NSManagedObject *managedObject;
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^(void) {
        managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName
                                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }];
    return managedObject;
}
```

Its breaking in the `createMyObject`-method after the return, which I guess is when the objects are being released. Is there anything special I missed with CoreData-concurrency and object-release? 
I've looked around and there isn't anything being mentioned about object-release, only about autoreleasepools which I'm not using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing the work in a `performBlockAndWait:` call, which is correct.  However, you proceed to return the object, presumably from a different thread.  That is not legal.  All managed objects must be accessed from the thread/queue on which they are created, with the exception of the `objectID` property, which is always valid.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. So basically I'm not allowed to give any objects out from my perform-block?

Comment: Correct.  The usual practice is to use completion blocks called from within the same context, or to pass `objectID`s and refetch into a different context.

Comment: Oh bummer. I think we'll have to remodel a lot of our software-architecture. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code to get managedObjectContext .managed objects must be accessed from the thread/queue on which they are created.

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
        NSThread *thisThread = [NSThread currentThread];
        if (thisThread == [NSThread mainThread])
        {

            if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
                return _managedObjectContext;
            }
            //
            if ([self persistentStoreCoordinator] != nil) {
                _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
                [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
            }
            [_managedObjectContext setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES];
            [_managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
            return _managedObjectContext;

        }
        else
        {
            //Return separate MOC for each new thread
            NSManagedObjectContext *threadManagedObjectContext = [[thisThread threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"MOC_KEY"];
            if (threadManagedObjectContext == nil)
            {
                threadManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
                NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
                [threadManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
                [[thisThread threadDictionary] setObject:threadManagedObjectContext forKey:@"MOC_KEY"];

            }

            return threadManagedObjectContext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have something like this implemented. This doesn't seem to be the problem here but rather an architecture-misconception as @Avi pointed out.